# Linking with static files on a nginx+gunicorn+flask system

Tags: python-2.7, nginx, flask, jinja2, gunicorn

I am setting up a flask web-app running on gunicorn with nginx as the back proxy.
For the life of me I cant figure out how to link static files in the template.
It keeps giving a 404 error when I try to access the linked file from the web-page, the path showing in the address bar as 127.0.0.1/static/styles/main.css which is obviously wrong. Template engine I am using is the default jinja2.
Here's the stylesheet code that I am trying to link with(file --- main.html).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/main.css') }}"/>
```

the folder structure is :

```
 entry.py
  /templates
    main.html
  /static
    /styles
    main.css
```

Do I need to make some changes to the nginx conf file or something?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you will.  In your server section of the nginx.conf file add something like this...

```
   # serve static files - each entry is a separate folder
      location ~ ^/(images|js|css|flash|media|static)/  {
      root    /var/www/html/Web;
      expires 30d;
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I added the lines.. It now says 403 Forbidden error. Do I need to change file permissions?

Comment: Yes - from the root execute "chown -R nginx {foldername}" and you should be good.

Comment: changed file permissions.. worked like a charm.. thanks a ton